# How do I solve HTTP Error 500.19, on External Host Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8.5

I had this error on my local machine, and I was able to give the file permission, but how to solve this error on my host server

I tried to edit `web.config`, but I still have the same error

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>  
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
<asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>

<handlers>
  <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600"></httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your host probably didn't install HttpPlatformHandler yet. Talk to them and not here.

**[Updated: For RC2 and above, a new module is required instead of HttpPlatformHandler, https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/164]**